Status and Shunning
Parents (and possible extended family) are very status-oriented.
They are the same or similar in:

Beauty
Strength
Intelligence
Highest Education Level
Profession
Job Title

The young man or woman that is not up to the mark is shunned.
The parents fabricate stories to keep up appearances and maintain a certain socialite status.
Is there a technical term for this in psychology other than shunning?
Thank you.
